# Scraping data from other sites and use it as a web service

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

I am trying to make a web service that scrapes data from a site but the one I made is not displaying on my browser. I am using Nodejs with Express framework.

My scores.js works, I can get JSON data from it if I run it on the command prompt but when I run it under the Express framework, nothing shows up on my browser.

This is the code I am using for my **server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var scores = require('./scores');

var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 80;
var router = express.Router();

router.use(function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('%s %s', req.method, req.path);
  next();  
});

router.get('/scores', function(req, res, next) {
  res.json({result : scores.getAll()});
});

app.use('/api', router);
app.listen(port);
console.log('Server listening on port ' + port);
```

And this my code for **scores.js**

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var requestify = require('requestify');
var rl = require('readline');
var prompts = rl.createInterface(process.stdin, process.stdout);

exports.getAll = function() {
  var jsonResponse;

  requestify.get('http://example.com').then(function(response) {
    var _response = {
      'results' : []
    };
    var title, link, runtime;

    response.getBody();
    $ = cheerio.load(response.body);

    $('.content').each(function() {
      $(this).find('a, img, span').each(function(i, elem) {
          if ($(this).is('img'))
            title = ($(this).attr('alt'));
          if ($(this).is('a') && $(this).attr('class') != 'preview')
            link = ($(this).attr('href'));
          if ($(this).is('span') && $(this).attr('style') == 'float:left;')
            runtime = ($(this).text().replace('time:', ''))
      });
      _response.results.push({"title" : title, "link" : link, "runtime" : runtime});
    });

    var jsonResponse = JSON.stringify(_response);
  });

  return jsonResponse;
}

prompts.question("Hit Enter to exit...\n", function() {
    process.exit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this line:

```
res.json({result : scores.getAll()});
```

in your `server.js`. However, the `scores.js` does not have the corresponding method `getAll()`.

Comment: I have changed the getHome() to getAll() still nothing showed up. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried returning `_response` in `scores.js` and use `res.json(scores.getAll());`? Looks like there is some problem in parsing the json.

Comment: I have finally fixed it. The changes I made were removing the "var" from "var jsonResponse = JSON.stringify(_response);" and using "res.json(scores.getAll());". Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problems. Glad you found out the double declaration problem. I did not see that.

Comment: I have another question if you don't mind. The first 2 or 3 requests that I made, no data are showing and after that it works well. Why is that?

Comment: I guess it either has to do with network latency or the async nature of node.js or the package that you are using.